# How to include switch statement in javascript for string

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

In my MVC application have included a button called form Field. whenever user clicks on that button dropdownlist gets displayed in modal box that contains text, checkbox etc as option.
code for form field and drop downlist:

```
<input type="button" id="FormField" name="Form Field" value="Form Field" style="width: 110px; height: 30px; background-color: #FFFFFF;"  onclick="return FormField_onclick()" />


function FormField_onclick(box) {
             dhtmlx.modalbox({
                 title: "Form Field Creation Tool",
                 text: "<div id='form_in_box'><div ><label>Type: <select id='Type' name='Type'><option>Text</option><option>Checkbox</option><option>Radio</option><option>DropDown</option><option>Listbox</option></select></label><br></div><div><span class='dhtmlx_button'><input type='submit' value='Select' style='width: 86px' onclick='Select_type(this)'></span><span class='dhtmlx_button'><input type='button' value='Cancel' onclick='close_file(this)' style='width:80px;'></span></label></div></div>",
                 width: "300px"
             });  
         }
```

Whenever user selects particular option from dropdownlist for example if user selects text option and clicks Select button than textbox should get inserted at cursor position.
code for select button:

```
 function Select_type(box) {
             var tp = document.getElementById('Type');

             switch (tp) {
                 case "text":
                     {
                     var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.message;
                        editor.insertHtml('<input type="text" id="tx" name="tx" style="width: 110px; height: 30px" />'); 
                 }
                     break;
                 case "Checkbox": { var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.message;
                                        editor.insertHtml('<input type="checkbox" id="chk" name="chk" value="Checkbox" style="width: 110px; height: 30px" />');} 
                     break;
                 case "Radio": 
                     { 
                 var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.message;
                 editor.insertHtml('<input "radio" id="rd" name="rd" value="radio" style="width: 110px; height: 30px" />');
}
                     break;
                 case "DropDown": alert("DropDown");
                     break;
                 case "Listbox": alert("Listbox");
                     break;
             }              
             dhtmlx.modalbox.hide(box);
         }
```

but this doesn't work for me. Even the alert doesn't work. And also don't know how can i include dropdown and list in it

Answer (score 1):

You want to do the switch on:

```
document.getElementById('Type').value
```

and not on the element it self, as it doesn't equals none of the cases you provided.

Comment: ok... It works .. Can you please tell me how can i include drop down and list in my application. Similarly the present code that am using for checkbox doesn't gets checked when I click on it. 
An empty checkbox without a check mark gets displayed

Comment: you can include a dropdown using the <select><option>Option1</option><option>Option2</option></select>, and Lists using <ul><li> some item</li><li>some other item</li></ul>. you can read here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html about ordered list (<ol>) and unordered list (<ul>) and lists in general.

Comment: but I want user to include option. I mean empty drop dwon list and the user will include the option in it based upon his/her needs

Comment: is this what you mean? http://jsfiddle.net/r89bC/ any way, create a new question for other questions you have.

Comment: Please check this site http://www.pdfescape.com/open/
in this site under create new pdf
there is a option called form field ..i want similar thing

Answer (score 0):

You could use an object literal for the switch statement if you wanted to...

```
var sw = {
    hello: function () {
        console.log("hello");
    },
    goodbye: function () {
        console.log("goodbye");
    }
}
var str = "hello";
sw[str](); //logs hello
```

Heres an explanation: http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/obj_lit.php

I think you need to clarify your question though and tag it appropriately...